# PHP echo Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, lightbox

I have a set of PHP code where if user key in the correct code in the text field, it will display a message below the text field and the next set of question comes out.

However, instead of displaying a message below the text field, I would like to know whether it is possible to have a jquery lightbox popup upon keying in the correct answer.

Here's my PHP code where it detects the correct answer. I store my data in an array:

```
if (isset($_POST) AND $_POST)
{
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $answer)
    {
        if (preg_match('/task([0-9]+)/i', $key, $matches))
        {
            $i = $matches[1];

            // check answer

            if ($data[$i]['answer'] == strtolower(trim($answer)))
            {
                $i += 1;
                $isCorrect = true;

            }

            $answered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code where it displays message below the text field.

```
<?php echo ($isCorrect)  ? 'That's correct!' : ''; ?>
```

Here's the jQuery lightbox code I want to integrate in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$("#dialog").jqm();
});
</script>

<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">
<a href="#" class="jqmClose">Close</a>
That's correct!
</div>
```

Help, anyone?

Comment: Is the AJAX already hooked up?

Comment: Make sure to fix the That's correct!.  You need to escape the apostrophe in That's.

Comment: @Flipper yupp, I substitute that to &apos;

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to POST the answer to your PHP script. In the Ajax success callback, trigger the dialog box with the appropriate text. Done!